# How to use task variables in loop in ansible?

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I have a structure where one variable is optionally derived

- from a given name
- from a given list
- from another variable

> ```
> - name: calling_task - one file
>   import_tasks: called_tasks.yml
>   vars: 
>     modulename: x
>     filenames: [ xy ]
> ```

or

> ```
> - name: calling_task - many files
>   import_tasks: called_tasks.yml
>   vars: 
>     modulename: x
>     filenames: 
>        - y
>        - z
> ```

or

> ```
> - name: calling_task - no files (implying filename = modulename)
>   import_tasks: called_tasks.yml
>   vars: 
>     modulename: x
> ```

In called_tasks.yml I used

> ```
> - name: copyfiles
>   copy:
>     src: "{{item}}"
>     dest: "/elsewhere/{{item}}"
>   loop: "{{filenames}}
> ```

This works fine for the first two cases, but how do I refer the other variable? I tried

> ```
>   loop: "{{filenames | default [ modulename ]}}
> ```

but this doesn't work. Any ideas please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems it works excactly that way I entered it here. In my original code, I omitted the blanks between square brackets and `modulename` which caused an error.

Comment: Wasn't it more missing a space between `default` and `[`? To avoid any interpretation problem, better to use parentheses when calling filters: `"{{filenames | default([modulename])}}"`. BTW, would have be good to give the error you were getting, always useful to find origin of a problem.